# Identify partition key of a Elastic Search Index

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

How can I know what is the partition key of an Elastic Search Index.
Any query by which I can fetch this information

Answer (score 0):

**Elasticsearch does not have a concept of a "partition key" like some other databases such as Cassandra. Instead, Elasticsearch uses a concept called "sharding" to distribute data across multiple nodes.**

The shard key is determined by a hash function applied to the document's ID, or if a custom routing value is used, the hash function is applied to this value.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html

You can check his article to understand cluster, node, and shard means. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scalability.html

Another article for routing.
https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/glossary/elasticsearch-routing/